# Write array to IStream

Tags: c++, windows, xmllite

I recieve some data as a char array. I want to pass this data to a method that recieves a stream (IUnknown *pInput).

I tried to debug this piece of code (using visual c++):

---

```
#include "xmllite.h"
#include <atlbase.h>
```

---

```
CHAR acTemp [100] = {0};
CComPtr<IStream> pDataStream;
HRESULT hr;

hr = IStream_Write (pDataStream, acTemp, sizeof (acTemp));
```

I get the error:

Unhandled exception at 0x75e49875 in SSL.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

I know that the following code that creates a strem from a file will work, but I didn't want to create a file just because I can't convert from the original array.

```
CComPtr<IStream> pFileStream;
LPCSTR szFileName = "FileName";
HRESULT hr;

hr = SHCreateStreamOnFile(szFileName, STGM_READ, &pFileStream);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specifically answer the question, the snippet is:

```
CHAR *acTemp;
acTemp = (CHAR *) GlobalAlloc (GMEM_FIXED, dwBytes);
memcpy (acTemp, acXml, dwBytes);
hr = ::CreateStreamOnHGlobal(acTemp, TRUE, &pDataStream);
```

In this case acXml is the char array containing the data to put in the stream.

I didn't find out why the previous did not work, but this one worked fine so far. Thanks @Matthias for the help!

Comment: You may also create the stream first, and then use its write method to fill the data, which is more straightforward.

Comment: @SamuelZhang, how would you do that? I'm having some troubles, I've tried this:


`IStream *pInput;`
`CHAR caStream [] = "asdkhgkjfhgdhg";`
`pInput->Write (caStream, sizeof (caStream), NULL);`


And got the error Unhandled exception at 0x002b1be2 in SSL.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: First of all, you need to create an instance of IStream, e.g. CreateStreamOnHGlobal with a NULL handler. Next, sizeof just returns the size of the char pointer. Please use ARRAYSIZE instead.

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
CComPtr<IStream> stream;
COM_VERIFY(::CreateStreamOnHGlobal(0, TRUE, &stream));
```

Its also possible to use GlobalAlloc to specify "own" memory to use. (in case your german is good - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/magazine/cc163436.aspx#S5 ).

Comment: Sorry, but how do I specify the content of this memory? How to link with "acTemp"? (this array will have some data input)

Comment: As the article says (in german :-) ) the memory to use is specified with the first parameter of CreateStreamOnHGlobal. The example gives 0  but it is possible to use GlobalAlloc. Maybe its not possible to connect to acTemp... Sorry :-(

Comment: I believe that the page in German is the sames as [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163436.aspx)